# Background Worker Thread error

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I'm getting this error:

`The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it`

On this part of code:

```
Private Sub loginWorker_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles loginworker.DoWork
        Try
            eFunctions._ValiAcc(My.Settings.adress, tbuser.Text, tbuser.Text & tbpwd.Password, eResult)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error!")
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Only the UI thread can touch UI controls, use a dispatcher to push the data back.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx

Comment: This example is clearer.  http://weblogs.asp.net/pawanmishra/archive/2010/06/06/understanding-dispatcher-in-wpf.aspx

Comment: So this:
`  Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(New Action(loginWorker_DoWork()), DispatcherPriority.Background)
` 
?